# How to distinguish betweeen parallel calls and sequential calls in jprofiler tracing session?

Tags: jprofiler

Can you pls help us answering the below questions.
1) While tracing/profiling a JAVA based web application using jprofiler is there any way to find out if the calls are parallel or sequential ?
2) While running Jprofiler on JVM where Wily tracing tool is already there, the jprofiler is mostly detecting the the overhead due to Wily tool rather than the actual application. Is there any way we can enable the jpropfiler filter to ignore Wily probes (e.g. ignore anything that starts with com.wily.*. Even after putting this filter in jprofiler exclude class filter, still jprofiler detects the Wily probes with com.wily.*). Can you pls suggest how to fix this in exclude filter ?
Also, is there any known conflicts/issues of jprofiler with Wily tool ?

Thanks,
PR

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to find out if the calls are parallel or sequential

No, the call tree cannot show this.

> Even after putting this filter in jprofiler exclude class filter, still 
>   jprofiler detects the Wily probes with com.wily.

That is because the calls from profiled classes are always shown and Wily instruments your code. You can configure a ignored method by right-clicking the Wily method in the call tree and choosing "Add filter from selection->Ignore method ...".

In general, I would not recommend to use multiple profilers or monitoring tools at the same time.